# Node.js + MongoDB: Generating shorter ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to create forum script with Node.js and MongoDB, but I have a problem with IDs which are pretty long in Mongo's case. I was already searching for solution, but I didn't find anything except the posts in which is written that I need to create ID's myself. I know more about PHP and MySQL, but I need Node for some realtime application in addition of forum. I would use generated ID for identifyng forum post, and next to it it would be thread's title - like this: address.domain/1/my-new-thread.

What do you recommend me?

Comment: Why exactly are the default ID's not good?

Comment: If I put them into address, the URL would be too long - address.domain/re2525435tr5435/my-new-thread-with-long-long-long-title

Comment: Take a look at this basic technique: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/  You could use it to generate the ID which you use directly, or build a map of "short id" to an ObjectId.

Comment: just generate your own id besides the mongodbid and use that as lookup for your posts/threads whatever, you can't shorten the mongodb generated id because its a BSONID and there is no shorter form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [mongoose-pureautoinc](https://github.com/mylovecompany/mongoose-pureautoinc) and it works without problems.

Comment: If you insist on answering your own question and accepting the answer so quickly, you could at least provide some source code on how you solved the issue.

Comment: @adrianp: the question is from March 2nd. What do you mean with "so quickly"?

Comment: @6502 Sorry, misread the date; still, can you provide some code example?